# Get posts from multiple categories with category

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get posts that have one (not all) of a particular set of categories that have a specified category.

For example, I want all posts with the categories Apples, Bananas, Oranges that have the category of GreenBeans.

How can I do this in Wordpress?

Comment: Yes you can do that. You can specific which categories to pull in the loop. Read the wordpress documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

```
$args= array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'category-1',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'category-2',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'category-3',
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'category-4',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'category-5',
        ),
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should check out the codex for Wp_query

example here below will return allpost with category name "staff" and "news":

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=staff+news' );
```

Check this page for more information:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can! That's the whole point of a CMS like WordPress. Start studying up... here is the documentation on the function [get_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms).

And everything else [WordPress Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page).

Good luck.